# is there any way to differentiate string and template string literal

Tags: typescript

```
type Data = {
  arrayObject: {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
  }[];
};

type ArrayElementType<A> = A extends readonly (infer T)[] ? T : never

type TupleOf<A extends number, R extends number[] = []> =
  R['length'] extends A ? R : TupleOf<A, [...R, R['length']]>;

type Integers = TupleOf<1>;

type Indexes = Integers[number];

type PathFinder<T, Key extends keyof T = keyof T> = Key extends string
    ? T[Key] extends (string | boolean | number | symbol)[]
      ? `${Key}.${Indexes}`
      : T[Key] extends object[]
        ? `${Key}.${Indexes}.${PathFinder<ArrayElementType<T[Key]>>}`
        : T[Key] extends Record<string, any>
          ? `${Key}.${PathFinder<T[Key]>}`
          : Key
    : never;

function register<Data>(name: PathFinder<Data>) {
  console.log(name)
}

const index = '0'

register(`arrayObject.${index}.lastName`); // break with variable 
register(`arrayObject.0.firstName`);
register(`arrayObject.0.firstNa`);
```

Is it possible to differentiate string and template string literal? The problem that I am facing is when a template string literal contains a variable, it will convert to `string`.

The solution so far is below: however, it's not ideal for our API, as `register` function doesn't expose to `Data` type.

```
type Test1<TName extends string> = string extends TName ? string : PathFinder<Data>;

function register<TName extends string>(name: Test1<TName>) {
  console.log(name)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeAoKU4CddwgDyARgFYQDGwAXOltlAGYCWuAzsAHJwC2EdTrhYA7AOYBuBtgA2cTj36Dgw8VOwBfANoBddczYK+AqENGSMGqRlCQoAQXyEAojIj8RwACrgIAHnsAPhQHKAgAD2AIEQATdihcCDgYgHsRGRAoAApRJghcKC8ASl0oAH5CqDoRCAA3fIwbX0KAVzA3IiYAsMjouKgRFt4SfIAaKAAlHqjY+MHh-NLUXWDkBgmtAHI3cWAAC02dab74+3LJqtb2iE6A8a0AOieJ8Y3t6LF9w51A61toACSnggYny8VQXjaHS6AEZfo1-lAgTEIhBwUjgaCOFp5iNcHoEc0AAoIPYAMVEKNwfi84wA0hBMhEZv0ANaMlJMSqodkgTmFVZQBlM3qzUwqczSc5eLTCo7Mk7ZMziKAAHygJBSKTccBEaoGQzx+vYIGG2pKOil2AqAAMACRoYUaB4O5Go9gaG1Wy4yuXHMUpchUYC6b3WqD2x2M52u2LumNoEn7Clx6mOAggVzuaLeXw02WMn6BT1hn0FkDy0X9CZUFK4GJ+ZVica6kCBUvhyNOl2J0kpqn5uXFr2MUeMOjCqXVOr5axMFoiagsNIJEEsTj5PzwRCBLIiYx0JPkymb7dwQJFejYShpdjaiAPGQpMR74xFSyNG8iThQE-hEKbAADJsjSJGI65RNSZ67jaeAZqQFDUD2f7OnIRj8DaRQSFAAD0OEaokcCslAADuLD7FAtR4CwcAkG4UAYGBEGngg55ZJsrAcNwxibFhQA)

Comment: is it converted to string when transpiled?

Comment: @DaniilLoban it's actually during the compile-time, there is a playground link above, you can reproduce the problem that I am trying to solve.

Comment: what is it? type Data = { 
  // firstName: string;
  /Û               incomplete code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your problem is that in TypeScript 4.1, the template literal *value* `` `arrayObject.${index}.lastName` `` is inferred to have a *type* of `string` instead of the desired [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) `"arrayObject.0.lastName"`:

```
const index = '0';

// TS 4.1    
const lit = `arrayObject.${index}.lastName`; 
// const lit: string
```

You can address this by using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), which tells the compiler to interpret such values as string literals (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40707](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40707)):

```
// TS 4.1
const litAsConst = `arrayObject.${index}.lastName` as const; 
// const litAsConst: "arrayObject.0.lastName"
```

So for your code in the Playground, you could write it like this:

```
register<Data>(`arrayObject.${index}.lastName` as const); // okay
```

---

Even better, it looks like TypeScript 4.2 will infer such literal types automatically in places where they are expected (such as declaring the variable as a `const`), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#41891](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41891)  Which means that `as const` will no longer be necessary:

```
// TS 4.2   
const lit = `arrayObject.${index}.lastName`; 
// const lit: "arrayObject.0.lastName"
```

and your original code will work with no changes:

```
register<Data>(`arrayObject.${index}.lastName`); // okay
```

[Playground link to TS4.1 code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmAJgUwB4wLwwOQAZsDcAUEaJLADZyxYAGAhgE6P0CeA8gEYBWywUAOgAkAbwQpUAXwEV60AHL0AtsloEYRAPSaYZaDCpQAXDGiMEAcxJ7K1AIIQAwuH10mLDjz6DR4tNNkFZVUYOV0XKHUtHRsDeycIkwAidzYuXn4BXBk5KEUVJJIwYIgAB3pgZBh2cwsYESIYGChWUqqAEXooekx6xtDmNK9+EwampoAzOEYglRMzS2Jxg1z85HmoczALJZhJAG0AXV2pmbzgja2dokliIha2mDtB1gBRCmQVMCgAFVbkAA8dgAfL07DA0FBkEgIDBGMh6IhwBRWDAABQICbIRgwH4ASiOMAA-LiYCYwMgAG7YkgPKo-ACupQ+7AmQIhqChMJgYAZSk42IANDAAEocrmIWG8-nYwlYI6gjD9EX7bAfbZQAAW2EO4uhkqexNFZNxTJZbLswv2AhtIuFKrV0IsWp1h2BdzpMAAkt9kBZsbCsIzmchWQCAIzu2n-b1INDIQOxqH+mb7aUCxjHaOPAAKXU1ADE-IwAT9hQBpZCoyH62EAayrIAmpKwDdYTdxipglernNrpk2ln6TRJP32Pd1Ne5aIW2xgAB8YJwQCAPvQwAueXyM5uIKx+auCYdh+MSbRRD3pKIfRIE5JaCemiYxxO9dyQMMoEdH6eYOeRJewgiDe8YQFeIh5lqRZxiWzweO8nzQr8-yluOVZusC94-k+uJoawk59tyIp8CAjCIACs4WMK66sMC2G-v+gGiJBhbFqhE6YQ+yzcSaPYnuSVLYncEwMmA-BwOAcJ+nA0DYgCnTdMCaLFHMMAsdBKAlgp9DAnifRNHoq7IDIIAWMpwR4jc1gRPAcboFgeDYCQ8IWDJUJaV0OlogwLzpN4QF+FIOSzCEYQ2HiUQuW5cnaUp2CnCF2ARTcQA)

[Playground link to TS4.2-dev code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20210101#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmAJgUwB4wLwwOQAZsDcAUEaJLADZyxYAGAhgE6P0CeA8gEYBWywUAOgAkAbwQpUAXwEV60AHL0AtslrEA9OphloMKlABcMAERMWHHn0G4ZcqIpXGSYZcggAHesGQx2jOADmMCJEMGEwUKzuPgAi9FD0mMGh4almbFy8-EYhqXnhAGZwjAquRtD+YAHE+fmypSrlUJXVKfmSANoAujW1RSX2ZTAVCK2pksRtEVE+AILMbACiFMgqYFAAKjMAPLMAfEmzMGhQyEgQMIzI9IjgFKwwABQIBciMMBsAlN0wAPwfMCMYGQADc3iRUpFoh8AK7uFbsAq7Y6oU7nGBgGFKThvAA0MAASii0YgLpjsW8flhugcMFNUgSOtgVlUoAALbBdYlnUkwI7-IlGDZwhFI2b4joCKUE-GM5lnALszldPaTSEzGAASXWyACbwuWGF8OQiO2AEZVRDwlCfNqJG4ktrTnqSh1yTjGD0YFawjaYAAFeJsgBi4je2w2+IA0sgHiceRcANaxkAFAFYZOsVMfWkwGNx1EJ4bNUb08L-DYdfNc+Pox4jKowAA+ME4IBAK3oYGbGKxHp7EFY2I73y6ZbC-1oonz0lEdrQbkktHHgI+VdjNcL6JAln43RXk+nsdnInnqEXwhEgfZoaQ4fm5mWqzOmx2lerez2S5XQvXrE3JIXASfAgIwiDbA2AT4l2rB7AeMBTiIM6XteIZhowEZ-iq361Ku+Y-hioJvGqhQwmA-BwOAly6nA0DhnECR7I8LiNAGQa3igGEMfQeyfMkuE6B2yAyCAATMa4nxTJIPraOAuhhugWB4NgMlXAEtGnFx8Q8Y8DALBYWSCKICnSPUgwqLQnwEDAmgwCAiZsN6qRqRp9HaUx2D9A0yDYFZRDSUAA)

Comment: what if the index is a variable type as a number?