# template string literal with variable cause: Argument of type s not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: typescript

This is a continuous question with this question: [is there any way to differentiate string and template string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534993/is-there-any-way-to-differentiate-string-and-template-string-literal)

```
type Data = {
  arrayObject: {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
  }[];
};

type ArrayElementType<A> = A extends readonly (infer T)[] ? T : never

type TupleOf<A extends number, R extends number[] = []> =
  R['length'] extends A ? R : TupleOf<A, [...R, R['length']]>;

type Integers = TupleOf<1>;

type Indexes = Integers[number];

type PathFinder<T, Key extends keyof T = keyof T> = Key extends string
    ? T[Key] extends (string | boolean | number | symbol)[]
      ? `${Key}.${Indexes}`
      : T[Key] extends object[]
        ? `${Key}.${Indexes}.${PathFinder<ArrayElementType<T[Key]>>}`
        : T[Key] extends Record<string, any>
          ? `${Key}.${PathFinder<T[Key]>}`
          : Key
    : never;

function register<Data>(name: PathFinder<Data>) {
  console.log(name)
}

const index = '0'

register(`arrayObject.${index}.lastName` as const); // works for TS 4.1
register(`arrayObject.${index}.lastName`); // works for TS 4.2

const i:number = '0'
register(`arrayObject.${index}.lastName` as const); fail
register(`arrayObject.${index}.lastName`); // fail
```

however, when the index is dynamic and the type will be `number`, eg it can result in a `for` `lop`, this breaks the type again. Is there a way to include the `number` or `string` type in the template string literal type?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmAJgUwB4wLwwOQAZsDcAUEaJLADZyxYAGAhgE6P0CeA8gEYBWywUAOgAkAbwQpUAXwEV60AHL0AtsloEYRAPSaYZaDCpQAXDGiMEAcxJ7K1AIIQAwuH10mLDjz6DR4tNNkFZVUYOV0XKHUtHRsDeycIkwAidzYuXn4BXBk5KEUVJJIwYIgAB3pgZBh2cwsYESIYGChWUqqAEXooekx6xtDmNK9%20EwampoAzOEYglRMzS2Jxg1z85HmoczALJZhJAG0AXV2pmbzgja2dokliIha2mDtB1gBRCmQVMCgAFVbkAA8dgAfL07DA0FBkEgIDBGMh6IhwBRWDAABQICbIRgwH4ASiOMAA-LiYCYwMgAG7YkgPKo-ACupQ%207AmQIhqChMJgYAZSk42IANDAAEocrmIWG8-nYwlYI6gjD9EX7bAfbZQAAW2EO4uhkqexNFZNxTJZbLswv2AhtIuFKrV0IsWp1h2BdzpMAAkt9kBZsbCsIzmchWQCAIzu2n-b1INDIQOxqH%20mb7aUCxjHaOPAAKXU1ADE-IwAT9hQBpZCoyH62EAayrIAmpKwDdYTdxipglernNrpk2ln6TRJP32Pd1Ne5aIW2xgAB8YJwQCAPvQwAueXyM5uIKx%20auCYdh%20MSbRRD3pKIfRIE5JaCemiYxxO9dyQMMoEdH6eYOeRJewgiDe8YQFeIh5lqRZxiWzweO8nzQr8-yluOVZusC94-k%20uJoawk59tyIp8CAjCIACs4WMK66sMC2G-v%20gGiJBhbFqhE6YQ%20yzcSaPYnuSVLYncEwMmA-BwOAcJ%20nA0DYgCnTdMCaLFHMMAsdBKAlgp9DAnifRNHoq7IDIIAWMpwR4jc1gRPAcaoOS27Yr0eDYCQ8IWDJUJaV0OlogwLzpN4QF%20FIOSzCEYQ2HiUTuZ5cnaUp2CnOF2DRTcQA)

Answer (score 4):

There is a small `StringNumber` hack.

Solution:

```js
const index = '0';

const lit = `arrayObject.${index}.lastName`;
// const lit: string

const litAsConst = `arrayObject.${index}.lastName` as const;


namespace Orig {
  type Data = {
    arrayObject: {
      firstName: string;
      lastName: string;
    }[];
    firstName: string;
  };

  type ArrayElementType<A> = A extends readonly (infer T)[] ? T : never

  type TupleOf<A extends number, R extends number[] = []> =
    R['length'] extends A ? R : TupleOf<A, [...R, R['length']]>;

  type Integers = TupleOf<1>;

  type Indexes = Integers[number];

  type PathFinder<T, Key extends keyof T = keyof T> = Key extends string
    ? T[Key] extends (string | boolean | number | symbol)[]
    ? `${Key}.${Indexes}`
    : T[Key] extends object[]
    ? `${Key}.${Indexes}.${PathFinder<ArrayElementType<T[Key]>>}`
    : T[Key] extends Record<string, any>
    ? `${Key}.${PathFinder<T[Key]>}`
    : Key
    : never;

  function register<Data>(name: PathFinder<Data>) {
    console.log(name)
  }

  type StringNumber<T extends number> = `${T}` // <---- my solution is here

  const index: StringNumber<0> = '0'
  const result = register<Data>(`arrayObject.${index}.lastName` as const);
  register<Data>('firstName');
}
```

Comment: @Bill did you find my answer helpful?